# Problem with own TCPServer

Tags: c#, tcp, telnet

I have written a TCP server. Then I am trying to connect to my server used Telnet (telnet localhost 2200). 
Problem: telnet write bad text - like this: **? ?????...**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        //UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        Byte[] message = encoding.GetBytes("Я занят...");

        try
        {
            IPAddress localAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAddress,2200);

            listener.Start(1);

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Сервер ожидает {0}", listener.LocalEndpoint);
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                NetworkStream io = client.GetStream();
                Console.WriteLine("Принято соединение от {0}", client.Client.RemoteEndPoint);

                Console.WriteLine("Отправляем сообщение...");
                io.Write(message,0,message.Length);

                Console.WriteLine("Закрытие соединения");
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Произошла ошибка {0}", e.Message);
        }
    }
```

The text on Russian language.If text on English then OK. 
What is the problem, may be codepage? Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCIIEncoding wont work with Russian. Use UTF8Encoding or UTF32Encoding (I'm unsure of which one that works with Russian).

Comment: I have change ASCIIEncoding on UTF32Encoding, but text is bad again:  /♦ 7♦0♦=♦O♦B♦...

Comment: Where are you outputting the text? You need to specify encoding there too.

Comment: I have output in standard windows telnet client fire up via command promt.

Comment: Then the standard telentclient doesn't support UTF. Putty (http://www.putty.org/) supports UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) gives better results. It does less interpreting of the returned data than telnet.